# Прописать путь к скрипту в другом файле

Tags: php, javascript

Скрипт 1 находится на: domains/site/script/function.php
Скрипт 2 на:           domains/site/include/connect.php

Каким образом прописать путь от одного файла к другому?

Путь /include/connect.php не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Относительный путь будет

> '../include/connect.php'

но лучше использовать абсолютный

> 'domains/site/include/connect.php'